# Como converter String Para INT na seguinte situação:?

Tags: php

Podem me ajudar a entender o que está acontecendo ?

Por que depois da conversão ele está imprimindo ZERO ? Tem haver com eu estar populando a var com uma função javascript pra detectar a resolução ???

```
<?php
$largura = "<script type =text/javascript> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>";

echo gettype($largura); //AQUI ELE IMPRIME string
echo $largura; //AQUI ELE IMPRIME 1366 

$largura = (int)$largura;

echo gettype($largura); //AQUI ELE IMPRIME integer
echo $largura; //AQUI ELE IMPRIME 0 

?>
```

Comment: Na verdade quando você faz `$largura = '<script type="text/javascript"> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>';` você não está passando o valor `"1366"` pra sua variável `$largura`. Você está atribuindo toda essa *string* pra sua variável, por isso o *casting* `(int)` retorna `0`.

Comment: Quando você dá o `echo` o código imprime `1366`, porque vai ser adicionado e executado o *script* no documento. Quem está imprimindo `1366` é o *JS*: `document.write(largura);`.

Comment: Basta substituir o valor da variável `$largura` na expressão `$largura = (int)$largura;` para ver o que se está querendo converter em INT. Fazendo a substituição temos:  `$largura = (int)<script type =text/javascript> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>;` Não dá para converter um javascript em INTEIRO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta substituir o valor da variável `$largura` na expressão

`$largura = (int)$largura;`

para ver o que se está querendo converter em INT.

Fazendo a substituição temos:

`$largura = (int)<script type =text/javascript> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>;`

Não dá para converter um javascript em INTEIRO.

> Na verdade, a conversão de string para inteiro depende do formato da string, assim o PHP avalia o formato da string e caso não possua nenhum valor numérico será convertido para 0(zero)

A respeito de  `echo $largura;`, substituindo o valor da variável `$largura` temos:

```
echo "<script type =text/javascript> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>"
```

que imprime na página um javascript que por sua vez imprime o valor da variável `largura`  com `document.write`.

> Veja o funcionamento [**aqui**](https://repl.it/@LeoCaracciolo/PessimisticLeanBoto). (não  permite javascript, portanto não executará o document.write)

Caso queira ver o javascript funcionando copie o código abaixo e cole nesta página http://phptester.net/

```
$largura = "<script type =text/javascript> var largura =  screen.width; document.write(largura); </script>";
echo "<br>";
echo gettype($largura). " AQUI ELE IMPRIME string";
echo "<br><br>";
echo "proxima linha é o javaScript veja no código fonte do frame direito";
echo "<br><br>";
echo $largura. " AQUI o JAVASCRIPT IMPRIME a largura";
echo "<br><br>querendo passar para INT um código javascript<br><br>";
$largura = (int)$largura;
echo $largura; 
echo "<br><br>";
echo gettype($largura). ' AQUI ELE IMPRIME integer porque agora $largura = 0';
echo "<br><br>";
echo $largura. ' AQUI ELE IMPRIME 0 porque $largura é 0';
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo, eu acabei resolvendo de forma mais simples, colocando as clausulas HTML dentro do IF do JS pois para fins de teste ele validava certinho. – Naimar Nunes agora   editar

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que a partir do momento que você passa a variável string como um tipo (int), a variável não reconhece os caracteres dentro da string como um valor numérico e coloca o valor 0. Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo, eu acabei resolvendo de forma mais simples, colocando as clausulas HTML dentro do IF do JS pois para fins de teste ele validava certinho. – Naimar Nunes agora   editar

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece pois quando você faz `(int)$largura`, o PHP não interpreta o código javascript, ele simplesmente pega todo o conteúdo e tenta transformar em um numeral. Como não há um número para ser retornado, ele retorna 0.

O primeiro resultado só aparece o número, pois o PHP está imprimindo esse código na página e o navegador está interpretando o código JS. Por isso a primeira forma funciona e a segunda não.

Talvez esse link o ajude.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504459/getting-the-screen-resolution-using-php

Comment: Muito Obrigado meu amigo, eu acabei resolvendo de forma mais simples, colocando as clausulas HTML dentro do IF do JS pois para fins de teste ele validava certinho.